# Getting socket connection error while trying to connect to hive from eclipse spring xml file

Tags: eclipse, spring, hadoop, hive

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hiveServer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:10000.

Answer (score 1):

May be improper bean declaration in config file.

You can follow below mentioned steps :

1. create hive-config.xml

   ```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:property-placeholder location="hive.properties"/> 
   <bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/>
   <bean id="hive-ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"
    c:driver-ref="hive-driver" c:url="${hive.url}"/>
   </beans>
   ```
2. create hive.properties

   ```
   hive.url=jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
   ```
3. add spring-jdbc jar
4. get connection in java code.

   ```
   ApplicationContext ac = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("hive-config.xml");
   DataSource dataSource =  (DataSource) ac.getBean("hive-ds");
   Connection con =dataSource.getConnection();
   ```

and start firing your queries to hiveServer